# Kafka 0.9.1 authorization

Tags: security, apache-kafka

I am exploring on the Security capabilities of Kafka 0.9.1 but unable to use it successfully.

I have set below configuration in my server.properties

**allow.everyone.if.no.acl.found=false
super.users=User:root;User:kafka**

I created an ACL using below command

**./kafka-acls.sh --authorizer-properties zookeeper.connect= --add --allow-principal User:imit --allow-host  --topic imit --producer --consumer --group imit-consumer-group**

and I see below response for it

**Current ACLs for resource `Topic:imit`:
        User:imit has Allow permission for operations: Describe from hosts: 
        User:imit has Allow permission for operations: Read from hosts: 
        User:imit has Allow permission for operations: Write from hosts:**

**Note:** Values mentioned in <> are replaced with some dummy values in the question and used correctly while creating the ACL

I have following observations:

a) Though I define the rule for imit topic to access for a particular using from a given host yet I can write to the topic from any host using any user account.

b) I am unable to read the messages from topic from any host or any user account (even using the one for which I have defined the rules).

I am running Kafka on RHEL 6.7 and all the users are local.

Appreciate if someone can guide if I am missing any configuration parameters or commands to manage authorization or if Kafka is behaving in a weird way.

Also where can I getting authorization related logs in Kafka?

Thanks & Regards,

Sudeep

Answer (score 2):

You are probably missing the below settings, in your Server.properties.

authorizer.class.name=kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer

-- Adding this line would enable the ACL to work via SimpleAclAuthorizer.
-- Kafka by default comes with the  kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer defined by the parameter authorizer.class.name

you can try the below setup which might give complete idea.

https://github.com/Symantec/kafka-security-0.9

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11695151)

Comment: I have included the required answer, the user has to add that property

Comment: You should explain what that lines does.

Comment: Added explanation.