# Unable to configure authorization with SSL in Kafka 0.10.2 (command line) - producer and consumer cannot Write to or Read from Topic

Tags: apache-kafka

I am unable configure authorization with SSL in Kafka 0.10.2. I am using command line clients for the broker, producer and consumer. The producer and consumer cannot Write to or Read from a test topic when `allow.everyone.if.no.acl.found=true` is commented out in the kafka server config file (otherwise, they are able to read and write)

I have scoured the [official documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/), [this Symantec setup](https://github.com/Symantec/kafka-security-0.9), [the Confluent docs](http://docs.confluent.io/3.1.1/kafka/security.html), and [various](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40664265/who-is-setting-up-the-authorizations-for-kafka-cluster/40988742#40988742) [Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40196689/kafka-topic-authorization-failed/40880940#40880940)-[Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37835199/kafka-java-producer-and-consumer-with-acl-enabled-with-topic) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35788922/kafka-0-9-1-authorization), but I still cannot get authorization working (though I have authentication via TLS working).

My certificates are from IdenTrust/Letsencrypt. If I uncomment `allow.everyone.if.no.acl.found=true`, I see this in the broker logs when the producer connects:

```
DEBUG SslTransportLayer:358 - SSL handshake completed successfully with
 peerHost 'devel-2.sjml.com' peerPort 56099 peerPrincipal 'CN=testkafkaconsumer1.eigenroute.com' cipherSuite 
'TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384'
```

and the producer is able to write to and the consumer is able to read from the test topic. This output does not, however, appear in the logs when the aforementioned line is commented out. In that case the producer command line client outputs the following:

```
WARN Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 10588 :
 {test100=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

Below is the ACL from Zookeeper for the topic test100, along with the command to list it:

```
$ bin/kafka-acls.sh --list --authorizer-properties zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181 --topic test100
Current ACLs for resource `Topic:test100`:
    User:CN=testkafkaconsumer1.eigenroute.com has Allow permission for operations: Read from hosts: *
    User:CN=kafka.eigenroute.com has Allow permission for operations: All from hosts: *
    User:CN=testkafkaproducer1.eigenroute.com has Allow permission for operations: Write from hosts: *
```

below are the commands I used to add users to the ACL:

```
./bin/kafka-acls.sh --authorizer-properties zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181 --add --allow-principal User:CN=kafka.eigenroute.com --operation All --topic test100
./bin/kafka-acls.sh --authorizer-properties zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181 --add --allow-principal User:CN=testkafkaproducer1.eigenroute.com --operation Write --topic test100
./bin/kafka-acls.sh --authorizer-properties zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181 --add --allow-principal User:CN=testkafkaconsumer1.eigenroute.com --operation Read --topic test100
```

OS: Debian 8 Jessie

Here are the config files for the broker, consumer, and producer:

broker config:

```
# secure-server-letsencrypt.properties
broker.id=0

delete.topic.enable=true

listeners=SSL://kafka.eigenroute.com:9093
port=9093
advertised.host.name=kafka.eigenroute.com
ssl.keystore.location=/home/kafka/keystore/kafka.keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=some-password
ssl.key.password=some-password
ssl.truststore.location=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/security/cacerts
ssl.truststore.password=some-password
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=HTTPS
ssl.client.auth=required
security.inter.broker.protocol=SSL

authorizer.class.name=kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer
super.users=User:CN=testkafkaproducer1.eigenroute.com
# allow.everyone.if.no.acl.found=true

advertised.listeners=SSL://kafka.eigenroute.com:9093

num.network.threads=3
num.io.threads=8
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600

log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs
num.partitions=1
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1
log.retention.hours=168
log.segment.bytes=1073741824
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000
```

consumer config:

```
# secure-consumer.properties
zookeeper.connect=127.0.0.1:2181

# timeout in ms for connecting to zookeeper
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000

#consumer group id
group.id=test-consumer-group

#consumer timeout
#consumer.timeout.ms=5000

security.protocol=SSL
ssl.truststore.location=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/security/cacerts
ssl.truststore.password=some-password
ssl.keystore.location=/home/kafka/keystore/testkafkaconsumer1.keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=some-password
ssl.key.password=some-password
```

producer config:

```
bootstrap.servers=kafka.eigenroute.com:9093

security.protocol=SSL
ssl.truststore.location=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/security/cacerts
ssl.truststore.password=some-password
ssl.keystore.location=/home/kafka/keystore/testkafkaproducer1.keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=some-password
ssl.key.password=some-password

compression.type=none
```

I would think that setting the producer user to be a super user, as I have done in the broker/server config, should allow the producer to write to the topic; alas, such is not the case. The broker seems unable to find the ACL from Zookeeper. Can someone suggest how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: Still no :-( . I've even tried the Kerberos route, but couldn't get that working either. Added a bounty just now - lets hope that helps in getting some suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in the [CLI documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#security_authz_cli) for the `--consumer` and `--producer` options, you need to allow DESCRIBE as well as READ on the topic for a consumer, also READ on the consumer group

For the producer you need DESCRIBE as well as WRITE on the TOPIC for a producer, also CREATE on the cluster.

Comment: This works - thanks! I executed the following lines: 

`./bin/kafka-acls.sh --authorizer-properties zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181 --add --allow-principal User:CN=testkafkaconsumer1.eigenroute.com --operation Describe --topic test100` 

and 

`./bin/kafka-acls.sh --authorizer-properties zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181 --add --allow-principal User:CN=testkafkaproducer1.eigenroute.com --operation Describe --topic test100`

To add the Describe permissions as you suggested, and now no more errors.